Forrest tree with nodes having text and images
Found the answers I needed here....what a prompt, helpful community! Thank you all.
I am trying to recreate this plot from MS Word

How does one create a node with wrapped text and an image below it?
Try 1)
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
-- +(0,-8pt)
-| (\tikzchildnode)}},
blank/.style={draw=none}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix
{
\node{\Tree 
 [.{Gaps and overlaps due to manufacturing process variation} 
    [.
    {Tape position variation } 
        [.{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{manuscript/src/figures/incorrectgeometry.jpg}}  {Robot inaccuracy}  {Tape lateral movement on the roller} ] 
    ]
    [.
    {Tape position variation} 
        [.{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{manuscript/src/figures/incorrectgeometry.jpg}}  {Robot inaccuracy}  {Tape lateral movement on the roller} ] 
    ]
    ]};\\
};           
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Breakdown of AFP manufacturing process variations which cause gap and overlap defects.}
    \label{fig:breakdown}
\end{figure*}


Try 2 (couldnt figure out the text part):
> \usepackage[edges]{forest} \begin{document} \forestset{   declare
> toks={graphics}{}, } \begin{forest}   before typesetting nodes={
>     for tree={
>       content/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={\includegraphics[#2]{#1}}{content()}{graphics()},
>     },
>     where={isodd(n_children())}{calign=child, calign child/.wrap pgfmath arg={#1}{int((n_children()+1)/2)}}{},   },   forked edges,  
> for tree={
>     parent anchor=children,
>     child anchor=parent,
>     l sep'+=3mm,
>     s sep'+=1mm,
>     fork sep'+=1mm,
>     edge={line width=1.5pt},   },   [incorrectgeometry.jpg, graphics={scale=0.1}
>     [incorrectgeometry.jpg, graphics={scale=0.1}
>       [incorrectgeometry.jpg, graphics={scale=0.1}]
>       [incorrectgeometry.jpg, graphics={scale=0.1}]
>       [incorrectgeometry.jpg, graphics={scale=0.1}]
>     ]
>     [incorrectgeometry.jpg, graphics={scale=0.1}
>       [incorrectgeometry.jpg, graphics={scale=0.1}]
>     ]   ] \end{forest}



Welcome. // What have you tried? // With this low amount of complexity you can just place a handful of nodes manually, including interconnections.

Hi I added the approaches I tried to the question

Just focus on \node in the pgfmanual, e.g. in its tutorials. Nodes hold text, including images. Make sure to tead about how nodes break lines …

And your Tikz code is … ? Please Unterstand, without your question will probably  be perceived as just another do-it-for-me request and closed pretty fast. // Click e.g. on your rightmost tag and learn from other questions posted here.

Ok, posts overlapped. Why do yo insist on forest?

Okay, Will try again using this information. Thank you for reviewing the question

You may also want to have a look at anchor s. E.g. when you have a node (T) with text and a node (I) with an image, you can anchor I.north to T.south, i.e. compound them together.

I suggest that you copy&paste your 6 images to your question, so other users here can download them and use with your posted code. However, there you should simplify the image names, i.e. drop all pathes, AND make your codes compile (some lines are simply missing to do that). Thank you

Please consider accepting the answer which helped you most/ you ended up using by clicking the thick to the top left of the answer you want to choose.

@cfr 'You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.'

@Bhuvan You can accept an answer regardless of reputation by clicking on the tick rather than the arrow. You can't vote for one, I know. In fact, only you can mark an answer as solving the problem.

You can set the text in \parboxes and add the image as a line after the box.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest, graphicx, duckuments}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={align=center, s sep=5mm, forked edge}
[Gaps and overlaps due to manufacturing process variation
    [Tape position variation\\{\includegraphics[width=4cm, height=1cm]{example-image-a}}
        [{\parbox[c][12mm]{32.5mm}{\centering Robot inaccuracy}}\\{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}}]
        [{\parbox[c][12mm]{32.5mm}{\centering Tape lateral movement on the roller}}\\{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}}]
    ]
    [Tape position variation\\{\includegraphics[width=4cm, height=1cm]{example-image-b}}
        [{\parbox[c][12mm]{32.5mm}{\centering Tape width variation}}\\{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}}]
        [{\parbox[c][12mm]{32.5mm}{\centering Tape compaction under roller}}\\{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}}]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}


Thank you latex ninja Sandy G

A style which took me longer than it ought based on Sandy G's answer.
\documentclass{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714910/ addasayd o ateb Sandy G: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714881/
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}
\forestset{%
  declare autowrapped toks={descriptor}{},
  declare autowrapped toks={image}{},
  declare dimen={align to}{0pt},
  align me/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={
      if={> Od > {align to}{0pt} } {%
        align/.process={ Ow {align to}{C{##1}} },
        tier/.option=level,
      }{},
    },
  },
  describe image/.style={%
    delay={
      align me,
      split option={content}{:}{temptoksc,temptoksa},
      if temptoksa={}{}{%
        descriptor/.register=temptoksc,
        image/.register=temptoksa,
        replace by/.process={OOOw3{descriptor}{node options}{align to}{[##1,append,align to=##3,##2,forked edge,l sep'=0pt,align me]}},
        delay={content/.option=image,no edge},
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    describe image,
    font=\sffamily,
    if level=1{% for the first level
      align to'=4cm,
    }{%
      if level=2{% for the terminal level
        align to'=3cm,
      }{%
        align=c, 
      },
    },
  },
  [Gaps and overlaps due to manufacturing process variation
    [Tape position variation:{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=1cm]{example-image-a}}
      [Robot\\inaccuracy:{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}]
      [Tape lateral movement on the roller:{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}]
    ]
    [Tape position variation:{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=1cm]{example-image-b}}
      [Tape width variation:{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}]
      [Tape compaction under roller:{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}

[No image due to Okular bug: apologies for the imaginative burden.]
From community, in 2 compile runs:


Thank you very much!

Here's some code getting you started into the directions I addressed in my comments above. I suggest to adopt a process of stepwise refinement:

(1) place all nodes you need first (e.g. absolute, as I did, using a matrix, using relative positioning via said library etc.)
(2) draw straight interconnects
all this helps you to put things at the right places
(3) refine the interconnects

ad 1, nodes

the top level is just a node (A) holding text
the second level is just for illustration, holding only a drawing in an other node (I1) and a \coordinate (which is a \node of extension zero, i.e. w.o. any content)
the third level shows you, how you can attach one node to the other via anchors

ad 2, lines
Did you connect what was intended? Can you leave nodes where they are?

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    % ~~~ (1) placing nodes first ~~~~~~~~~~
    %     top level
    \node (A) at (0,0) {Gaps and overlaps due to manufacturing process variation};
    
    %     first level
    \node       (I1) at (-3,-2) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{tape}};
    \coordinate (I2) at (3,-2); % just a dummy
    
    \node (T2) at (-5,-4) {Robot inaccuracy};
    \node[anchor=north,yshift=-3mm]
               at (T2.south) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{robot}};
    
    % ~~~ (2) draw some lines ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (A) -- (I1);
    \draw (A) -- (I2);
    
    \draw (I1) -- (T2);
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

ad 3, refining lines, i.e. introducing meandering
See e.g. this answer which uses intermediate points.
about class standalone
Why using it? because developing drawings will be easier. See e.g. this example to include them as pdf in other documents.
images
I cut them out from the overall drawing; can't paste them here as they are ... too small to be uploaded ...
